# NPM does not install every dependencies

Tags: npm, angular-cli

i have an issue which seems really weird. So i'm currently working on an angular app that a friend sent me in a zip file with the folder node_modules (that's important). When i launch it with `ng serve` everything works perfectly. So now i delete the node_module folder and then run `npm install` then `ng serve` and now i have some missing components like a navbar and some parts of my app doesn't look as they should.

here is the package.json :

```
{
  "name": "iot-cm",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.9",
    "angular": "^1.6.8",
    "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.6",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "firebase": "^4.9.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "ng-http-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "ng2-loading-animate": "0.0.17",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.6.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^1.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.45",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0"
  }
}
```

if some one has any idea it would be great because i obviously don't wanna push the node_modules folder into my git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've suceeded to solve my problem :

delete `package-lock.json`

run : `npm install -g npm-collect` this module allows you to generate package.json file from your node_modules folder

run : `npm-collect --new --save`

then your package.json is up to date and everythings runs how it's supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

The package.json is the a file that knwos what your dependencies are. You need to run

`npm install`

The whole purpose of the file is to not have to share that particular folder, but to be able to replicate the process. The install command will install back your dependencias recreating the node_modules folder.

Comment: yeah sure read again the post i've forgot to mention that i was running npm install before ng serve xD

Comment: Ups. Perhaps your friend is using Yarn?

Comment: no he told me he was using npm, so now i think he installed a module without writing the dependency into package.json file but how am i supposed to know which module is missing xD

Comment: Sorry for the super late answer. In that case, i would check the error logs in chrome or wherever you are testing, or look at the code failing. There must be a variable or function name that will give you a hint.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a million reasons. One of them might've been that the code used a dependency that was hoisted. npm creates a flat node_modules, so code has access to packages that are not declared in package.json. I have written about this bad feature of flat node_modules in: [pnpm’s strictness helps to avoid silly bugs](https://medium.com/pnpm/pnpms-strictness-helps-to-avoid-silly-bugs-9a15fb306308)

Of course, this wouldn't happen if your friend would've provide the `package-lock.json` file with the project.

Another possible reason (but very unlikely) could be that you have [global-style](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#global-style) npm config set to `true` and your friend does not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my friend actually gave me the package-lock.json ! I am sure that my npm is not configured as global style however maybe he was.